# Изменить кодировку xml-файла

Tags: c#

Я создаю XML файл по данным dataGridView. Если в заголовках столбцов находятся русские слова, то в файле этот столбец пустой. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Вы покажете нам релевантную часть кода, или нам нужно догадаться, где именно вы выбрали не ту кодировку?

Comment: Вот код, простите, догадываться не нужно.
http://pastebin.com/T1rwQBjs
Я менял Encoding.Unicode на Encoding.GetEncoding(1251) и Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251"), но он тогда вообще не читал файл.

Comment: @elfinorr: В коде всё выглядит правильно. А почему вы думаете, что в файле текста нет? Как вы читаете файл?

Comment: Добавил компонент CrystalReport, через "Мастер создания стандартных отчётов" - "Создать новое соединение" - "ADO.NET" - И указываю путь к файлу xml. Причем если делать это, когда поля имеют русские названия, то я не могу добавить на следующем шаге поля в отчёт, просто ничего не происходит.
Ну не то что нет,а он просто не отображается, я думаю. Просто пустое место там.

Comment: @elfinorr: А вы сами в файл смотрели? Текстовым редактором? Может, проблема у CrystalReport?

Comment: Во всех файлах текст остается, если открыть текстовым редактором. Но если открыть файлы в браузере, то результаты разные. Там, где кодировка (1251), Хром выдает ошибку с кодировкой. А как тогда кодировку надо указывать?